# Add local image to gt table header larger

Tags: html, r

I am trying to make the local image in this header larger.  I am currently using html code to format the image within the gt table of R.

Here is an example of my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

pizza_filename <- file.path("C:","
                            "Documents",
                            "pizza.png")

pizzaplace %>%
  mutate(type = case_when(
    type == "chicken" ~ "chicken (pizzas with chicken as a major ingredient)",
    type == "classic" ~ "classic (classical pizzas)",
    type == "supreme" ~ "supreme (pizzas that try a little harder)",
    type == "veggie" ~ "veggie (pizzas without any meats whatsoever)",
  )) %>%
  mutate(size = factor(size, levels = c("S", "M", "L", "XL", "XXL"))) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(type, size) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(
    sold = n(),
    income = sum(price)
  ) %>%
  gt(rowname_col = "size") %>%
  tab_header(title = html(gt::local_image(pizza_filename), "<b>", 
                          "Pizzas Sold",
                          "</b><br>", "in 2015")
               ) %>%
  fmt_number(
    columns = vars(sold),
    decimals = 0,
    use_seps = TRUE
  )
```

The image is correctly displaying (and saving) which is a major improvement from my previous question on this issue.  However, now I would like the image to span the two lines of the title text rather than just the one, as indicated by the drawn red box on the output below.  Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest to use regular html table formatting like:

```
tab_header(title = html("<table><tr><td align='center' valign='center'>", 
                      gt::local_image(pizza_filename, height = 120, width = 120),
                      "</td><td><b>Pizzas Sold</b><br>in 2015</td></tr></table>")
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to do a minor adjustment to make it work:

Comment: tab_header(title = html("<table><tr><td align='center' valign='center'>", 
                      gt::local_image(pizza_filename, height = 120, width = 120),
                      "</td><td><b>Pizzas Sold</b><br>in 2015</td></tr></table>")

Comment: oops. you're right. :) i've edited my post.

Comment: Do you know how to expand the title block over the entire table?

Comment: Hm. I don't know how your table is embedded. You can put the image in a new row with <tr><td> and use either the width tag or colspan. Maybe u should take a look at basic html table formatting or use an online wysiwyg tool.